# Jackson JSON - Strip Timezone from Calendar object while deserializing

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have jackson deserializer to convert the date in json string into a calendar object. I am passing "2015-10-22" in the request and it gets converted to "2015-10-22-04:00" after I convert it to a calendar object. Is there a way to suppress the timezone from being sent? In scenarios where  use XMLGregorianCalendar , I am using "date.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED)" to suppress the timezone.

```
private static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

@Override
public Calendar deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext arg1) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String dateString = jsonparser.getText();
    try {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(formatter.parse(dateString));
        return calendar;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Calendar`. If you don't care about a timezone, it seems like `java.time.LocalDate` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No timezone was sent, so question "Is there a way to suppress the timezone from being sent?" is meaningless.

The `Calendar.getInstance()` method assigns a default timezone, see javadoc:

> Gets a calendar using the default time zone and locale. The `Calendar` returned is based on the current time in the default time zone with the default locale.

You then replace the "current time" with the call to `setTime()`, but the time zone and locale remain unchanged.

A `Calendar` object will *always* have a time zone and a locale.